# How is a private blockchain different from a public blockchain?

Tags: private-blockchain

I'm building a project that will remain heavily between the limitations of a private blockchain.

These are my questions about the limitations or advantages of a private blockchain.

- Do you have to pay gas for transaction on a private blockchain?
- If there is no gas, How do miners fit in? How are transactions mined?
- What happens if the computer running the software for the private blockchain shuts down, does it mean that the blockchain will restart from block0 or the blockchain will not be affected.
- Can wallets such as Metamask be used for accounts on a private blockchain?
- What sort of hardware would an organization need to run its own private blockchain?
- Will I be able to create / deploy smart contracts on a private blockchain?
- Would a private blockchain provide the same security standard as the main chain?

I know these question sound a little stupid, but they have a big impact on my project. And I cannot find a clear cut answer on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Simple just make a **private hidden mempool** with same protocol as a public blockchain

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, one organization owns and runs a private blockchain. They give blockchain users more control, scalability, and privacy over the data that is being used. Transactions on private blockchains can only be seen by users who have been given permission, and nodes on the network usually talk to each other through a secure server. Public blockchains, on the other hand, are open to anyone who wants to use them. They are less centralized, which means they are not managed and protected by a single group.

Comment: so who are the nodes in a private blockchain?